# Invert and center origin on html canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas, transform

I have inverted and centered the origin in my canvas, but the y-axis doesn't seem to scale like my x-axis.

I'm setting the transform like so

```
context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, -1, (canvas.width/2), (canvas.height/2));
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SHbkb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of re-setting the canvas width and height using CSS, reset directly on the canvas element.

The default canvas size is 300x150 so when you CSS style to 400x400, you are actually stretching the canvas height.

So do it this way in javascript:

```
canvas.width=400;
canvas.height=400;
```

Comment: The default vertical size of the canvas is 150 pixels tall.  When you use CSS to scale the canvas, you're not adding any vertical pixels to the canvas.  Instead, the browser "stretches" each of the 150 pixels to fit into the new 400 pixel height.  When you use canvas.height=400, **you are actually adding 250 pixels** to the canvas height. Cheers!